# iOS when should @property be in .h and when in .m

Tags: ios, xcode

I understand that methods available for other classes  to call should be in the header file..but I'm a little confused when the @property should be in the header file and when it should be in the implementation file.

How do you make that decision, and what difference does it make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any property that you want publicly exposed to the other classes goes in the .h file. The 'private' properties (pun intended) go in the implementation file in a anonymous category or class extension. You might also make the .h version of the property readonly for example, and the .m version readwrite.

### An implementation file with properties defined in a Private Category

```
@interface CPClassFileName ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;
@end



@implementation
...
@end
```

Comment: This technically a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) not a private category. An important distinction is that methods defined in class extensions are _required_ to be defined in the class @implementation block. A class extension is exactly the right thing to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You put the @property on the header if you want other classes (or developers) to know that there are accessors to your ivars.

To rephrase :
If you want "public" getter / setter you put the @property on the header. If you want them private you put the @property on the .m file.